# Null hypothesis or alternative hypothesis

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test, z-test

Actually I'm a bit confused how to choose my NULL hypothesis and how to choose the alternative one. suppose I have a sample of salary with mean 112,000 and I want to check if the population has mean greater than 112,000$ , what will be my NULL hypothesis?.

Comment: The thing you want to show is the alternative hypothesis. It's contrary the null hypothesis. If you are unsure, maybe a two sided test would be more appropriate.

Comment: So in my example the Null hypothesis is the mean less than 112,000 $ !?

Answer (score 3):

Plenty of sttistics teachers, particularly in intro classes (say AP stat), will write $H_0: \mu = 0$ vs $H_a: \mu <0$, but it's really $H_0: \mu \ge 0$ vs $H_a: \mu <0$.

The choice of null and alternative hypothesis is exactly that: a choice. A lawmaker may want to know if tax reform caused a decrease in inequality. If the tax reform increased inequality, sure, that contradicts $H_0: \mu = 0$, but it's not the desired effect. It's actually worse than doing nothing at all. Similarly, if you only care about whether or not two parameters are the same, the two-sided test would be appropriate.

It's completely dependent on your research question.

Comment: so my desired effect is the alternative hypothesis !?

Comment: @AbdEl-RahmanAkram yes but here you will see very soon what the issue is.... write down the test appropriately and it’s statistic and look at what happens. Hint: if the sample mean is assumed to be the best representation of the population mean and the deviation from that mean in the population have a certain distribution, then build the statistic and see what its value is..I’ll help you: the test becomes H0 m=112000 vs H1 m>112000, then do the calculations :-)

Comment: @Fr1 in my example in the question is the null hypothesis is the mean less than 112,000 $?

Comment: @AbdEl-RahmanAkram no the alternative is more than 112000

Comment: @Fr1 is that differs from what i said !?.

Comment: @AbdEl-RahmanAkram no but the point here is that if you have a sample mean of 112000 and you ask a test whether the population has mean higher than that, clearly the test will respond “no” :-) that is the reason why I was saying so..

Comment: @Fr1 can I ask why we can't reverse them and what happen if we reverse them !?

Comment: @AbdEl-RahmanAkram the result of the test will not change because your statistic will be always 0 if you have a sample mean of 112000 and you ask a test whether the population mean is higher or lower or different than 112000. That was why I was smiling.. Anyway if you have to write it down in an appropriate way, the “higher” will be the correct way

Comment: I'm really get lost in all of that can you breif me all of that :-)

Comment: Just do the test with the alternative m>112000 and the rest will come along